# EqualsIgnoreCase en Javascript

Tags: javascript

En Java, se utiliza el método `equalsIgnoreCase()` para comprobar la independencia entre mayúsculas y minúsculas. **¿En Javascript?**

Tengo el siguiente ejemplo: realizar la función "`existeDisco(titulo):boolean`".
Devuelve verdadero si existe el disco cuyo título coincide con el que se pasa como parámetro. **El método es independiente de mayúsculas/minúsculas.**

Código de la función que pide:

```
this.existeDisco = function (nombreRecibido){
        for(var i=0; i<this.arrayDiscos.length; i++){
            var nombre = this.arrayDiscos[i].nombre;
            if(nombre == nombreRecibido)
                return this.arrayDiscos[i];
        }
        return false;
    }
```

¿Cómo hacemos que la función detecte el `nombreRecibido` tanto en mayúsculas o minúsculas siempre y cuando sea el nombre exacto? Es decir: "Fernando" o "FERNANDO" o "fernando".

Answer (score 1):

Haz un parse a Mayusculas[`toUpperCase()`] o Minusculas[`toLowerCase()`]

```
this.existeDisco = function (nombreRecibido){
    for(var i=0; i<this.arrayDiscos.length; i++){
        var nombre = this.arrayDiscos[i].nombre;
        if(nombre.toUpperCase() == nombreRecibido.toUpperCase())
            return this.arrayDiscos[i];
    }
    return false;
}
```

O puedes intentar con Expresiones regulares algo asi:

Usando RegExp.test

```
this.existeDisco = function (nombreRecibido){
    var regex = new RegExp("^"+nombreRecibido+"$","gi")
    for(var i=0; i<this.arrayDiscos.length; i++){
        var nombre = this.arrayDiscos[i].nombre;
        if(regex.test(nombre))
            return this.arrayDiscos[i];
    }
    return false;
}
```

O usando String.match()

```
this.existeDisco = function (nombreRecibido){
    var regex = new RegExp("^"+nombreRecibido+"$","gi")
    for(var i=0; i<this.arrayDiscos.length; i++){
        var nombre = this.arrayDiscos[i].nombre;
        if(nombre.match(regex))
            return this.arrayDiscos[i];
    }
    return false;
}
```

Una forma simplificada, pero con menos rendiemiento:

```
this.existeDisco = function (nombreRecibido){
    var regex = new RegExp("^"+nombreRecibido+"$","gi")
    var disco = this.arrayDiscos.find(disc){
        return disc.nombre.match(regex);
    };

    return disco ? disco :false;
}
```

Comment: En mi ejemplo, ¿lo tendría que realizar por "nombre" y "nombreRecibido"? No existe en Javascript un método como puede ser IgnoreCase?

Comment: La verdad no he sabido de su existencia

Comment: Ya cambie el codigo ejemplo en base al codigo de tu pregunta, espero te sirva

Comment: Esto fallaría en muchos casos. Es un error grave llamar al constructor de RegExp sin escapar caracteres especiales

Comment: Creo que votar negativo a la respuesta no ayuda a nadie, en caso de que se haya votado negativo por el error que menciona @Mariano, pienso que es mas util actualizar la respuesta corrigiendo el error

Answer (score 0):

Otra opcion seria crear la funcion `equals` en la Clase `String` y que reciba como parametros el valor a comparar y una bandera indicando si es `IgnoreCase` o no.

Defines la funcion de la siguiente manera;

```
String.prototype.equals = function(value, ignoreCase) {
    var i = ignoreCase ? "i":"";

    var regex = new RegExp("^"+value+"$","g"+i);
    return this.match(regex);
};
```

La usas asi:

```
this.existeDisco = function (nombreRecibido){
    for(var i=0; i<this.arrayDiscos.length; i++){
        var nombre = this.arrayDiscos[i].nombre;

        //comparas el resultado de equals, si son iguales retornara la cadena, si no, retornara null
        if(nombre.equals(nombreRecibido, true))
            return this.arrayDiscos[i];
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Generar un regex así, sin escapar caracteres especiales es un error grave! Ejemplo: `"ABC".Equals("A|bcdefg")`

Comment: ¿Por qué publicaste 2 respuestas?

Comment: Cierto, olvide ese pequeño detalle de los caracteres de escape de las expresiones regulares. Estaba indeciso si hacerla en la misma o hacer otra, decidi hacer dos porque eran dos respuestas diferentes